# Output VBA Array Elements to One Cell in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, output, vba

So i have a vba code that creates an array with multiple elements. I would like to output those elements into one cell in excel. Im able to output its elements to multiple cells but prefer it in one cell. Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

If the array is declared as a String or Variant then you can use `Join`:

```
Sub AllIntoOne()
    Dim arr(1 To 3) As Variant
    arr(1) = 4
    arr(2) = 54
    arr(3) = 3
    Range("A1") = Join(arr, ",")

End Sub
```

The delimiter "," defaults to a space if not supplied, but can be an empty string "" if no separation is required.

Comment: Awsome! Thanks for your prompt reponse!

Comment: Yes sir, it worked like a charm! Again, thank you for your response!