# Output VBA Array of Doubles to One Cell in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to dump the content of an array of Doubles into a single Cell in Excel with VBA.

I found [an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543517/output-vba-array-elements-to-one-cell-in-excel), which solves the problem for Strings or Variant, but not for Double.

```vb
Dim arr(1 To 3) As Double
arr(1) = 0.81
arr(2) = 0.95
arr(3) = 1.74

Worksheets("Test").Cells(1,1).Value = dump(arr, ";")
```

The Last line should write all the values from the Array to the Cell specified.

**Edit**: Changed 0,81 to 0.81 etc. (German System vs. International Standard)

Comment: Just loop and concatenate the values into a string with whatever delimiter you want.

Comment: `Join(WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 1, 0), ";")`

Comment: The original code also works properly. Simply replace "dump" with "Join" and change formatting of your numbers (dots instead of commas); array as Variant.
Result: `0.81;0.95;1.74`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a string anyway, looping or transposing or Use of Index(nice omegastripes):
(plus change the , to .)

```
Dim arr(1 To 3) As Double
arr(1) = 0.81
arr(2) = 0.95
arr(3) = 0.74

Worksheets("Test").Cells(1, 1).Value = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(arr)), ";")
```